# what should the relationship be on three entities--Complaint, Reporter, Reported

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, database-design

I'm designing a DB for a complaints service.

Main entities: Complaint, Reporter, Reported.

Reporters can add multiple complaints and the reported have multiple complaints attached to them using the same phone number.

> The Reported entity has the information about every reported numbers such as phoneNumber, status, etc. The Reporter entity has the information about the reporters, phone number, name, etc. Every reporter can submit multiple complaints about multiple reported numbers. All these complaints should be saved in the Complaint entity, and every reported number can have multiple rows each with different types of complaint.

How should the relationship between these three entities look?

What I was thinking:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "complaints_tbl")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Complaint extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "complaint_Id", nullable = false)
    private Long complaint_Id;

    @NotNull
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "issuing_date", updatable = false)
    private LocalDate issuingDate;
    private String message;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "reporter_Id")
    private Reporter reporterId;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "reported_Id")
    private Reported reportedId;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "operator_Id")
    private Operator operator;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private Enum Type;

    private int complaint_Counter;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table
@Getter
@Setter
public class Reported extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "reported_Id",  nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long reported_Id;

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String reportedPhoneNumber;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String status;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table
@Getter
@Setter

public class Reporter extends BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "reporter_Id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long reporter_Id;

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String reporterPhoneNumber;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private int numberOfComplaints;
}
```

Comment: It seems you actually want help with the database design. In that case you should tag the request `database-design`. What you are showing, however, is not some tables and columns, but a lot of Java code. That obfuscates the real task for me. Are you looking for a database design or are you looking for a method to introduce that design in Java?  Well, maybe some spring-boot / jpa person can help you here. (You should remove the `sql` tag, because you have no problem with some SQL statement. And remove the `database-administration` tag. The tag description says it is inapproprate here.)

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck on what step among which steps following what published presentation of what design method? [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that In order to do the right design I will have to join the columns from reporter and reported entities using Id as a foreign key.

In order to make this design, in the complaint entity we should include the following :-

```
 @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "reporter_Id")
    private Reporter reporterId;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "reported_Id")
    private Reported reportedId;
```

But using Id can be a little bit confusing so instead I could use phoneNumber for Reporter and Reported as the foreign key.